# jQuery toggle change inner html of a button in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two elements

```
<div id="searchInput">
This is something
</div>

<button type="button" id="dugme" onclick="th()" > Show </button>
```

**I want to toggle (in jQuery) the searchInput (hide and show) and change the button text from Show to Hide.**

The `searchInput` isn't the problem, I just do this:

```
function th(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var forma = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        var dugme = document.getElementById("dugme");
        $(forma).toggle();
    });
}
```

But when I want to change the innerHTML in the toggle nothing happens. This is what I tried:

```
function th(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var forma = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        var dugme = document.getElementById("dugme");
        $(forma).toggle(function(){
            $(dugme).innerHTML = "Hide";
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: you are mixing pure javascript and jquery, try to write code in one particular style

Comment: Also there is no need to use a ready event handler inside  a function that is called from the html onclick attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$(dugme).html("Hide");` because `$(dugme)` is a jQuery object. You also do not require a `document.ready` handler within a function.

```js
function th() {
  var forma = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  var dugme = document.getElementById("dugme");
  $(forma).toggle(function() {
    $(dugme).html("Hide");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchInput">
  This is something
</div>

<button type="button" id="dugme" onclick="th()"> Show </button>
```

`innerHTML` do not work in jQuery objects so you need to remove `$` as:

```js
function th() {
  var forma = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  var dugme = document.getElementById("dugme");
  $(forma).toggle(function() {
    dugme.innerHTML = "Hide";
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchInput">
  This is something
</div>

<button type="button" id="dugme" onclick="th()"> Show </button>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that was just being used as OP has mentioned. Nevertheless, it is of no use. I corrected my answer also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes when you're trying to call the element property `innerHTML` on jQuery object, you could use `html()` instead but since you're changing just the text it will be better to use `.text()` like:

```
$(dugme).text("Hide");
```

You could use `.is(':visible')` to toggle the text like:

```
forma.toggle(function() {
  dugme.text(forma.is(':visible') ? "Hide" : "Show");
});
```

```js
function th() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var forma = $("#searchInput");
    var dugme = $("#dugme");

    forma.toggle(function() {
      dugme.text(forma.is(':visible') ? "Hide" : "Show");
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="searchInput">
  This is something
</div>

<button type="button" id="dugme" onclick="th()"> Hide </button>
```

Comment: You're marking the other answer as correct when it's clearly doesn't toggle the text 'Hide/show" do you have any reason ?!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    function th(){

            var forma = $("#searchInput");
            var dugme = $("#dugme");
            forma.toggle(function(){
                var txt = forma.is(':visible') ? 'Hide':'Show';
                gugme.text(txt);
            });

    }
```

Comment: The `var txt = forma.is(':visible') ? 'Hide':'Show';` Helped with the toggle. Thank you ths!

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<div id="searchInput">
This is something
</div>

<button type="button" id="dugme">Hide</button>
```

Jquery

```
$('#dugme').click(function(){

if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Hide') {
        $(this).text('Show');
        $('#searchInput').hide();
    } else {
        $('#searchInput').show();
        $(this).text('Hide');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/615631/)